# How to enqueue javascript for WP Customize options sidebar?

Tags: theme-development, themes, wp-enqueue-script, theme-options, theme-customizer

I'm trying to add Chosen.jquery to the WP Customize options panel, so I can have an autocomplete box there. Is there any way I can do that? I tried with **admin_init**, **admin_footer** and **admin_print_footer_scripts** actions, but none seems to work inside of the Customizer.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the action `customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`:

```
add_action( 
    'customize_controls_enqueue_scripts', 
    'enqueue_customizer_scripts' 
);

function enqueue_customizer_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script(); // fill in the details here
}
```

To add inline scripts in the header, use the action `customize_controls_print_scripts`.

See `wp-admin/customize.php` for details.

Answer (score 0):

That was bug in core, fixed in [#27619](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/27619), now you can just use `admin_print_footer_scripts` for example.